# Rails view is printing certain values we want from a hash and then the full hash - WHY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, hash, controller

We're trying to build a feed of submitted comments and articles, calling and showing only certain attributes of each.  We're able to get a feed of sorts, but the page is also returning a hash of all of the attributes of the articles and comments.  See below:

Controller:

```
  def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
      # @feed= (Article.all + Comment.all).sort!{|a,b| a.updated_at <=> b.updated_at}.reverse.take(10)

  comments = Comment.all
  comments_array = []
  comments.each do |f|
    comment_info ={}
    comment_info['feed_text'] = f.commenter + ' submitted to a goal'
    comment_info['time_stamp']=f.updated_at
    comments_array<<comment_info
  end

  articles=Article.all
  articles_array =[]
  articles.each do |f|
    article_info ={}
    article_info['feed_text']='A new goal has been created:' + f.title
    article_info['time_stamp']=f.created_at
    articles_array<<article_info
  end



  @feed = (comments_array + articles_array).sort!{|a,b| a['time_stamp'] <=> b['time_stamp']}.reverse.take(10)

  end
```

View:

```
        <p>
        <%= @feed.each do |f| %>
        <p>
            <%= f['feed_text'] %>
        </p>
        <% end %>

        </p>
```

Below shows what is being shown on the page:

```
#what_we_want:
```

2 submitted to a goal

new submitted to a goal

A new goal has been created:test 6

A new goal has been created:test2

```
#what_we_don't_want:
```

[{"feed_text"=>"2 submitted to a goal", "time_stamp"=>Thu, 31 Jul 2014 19:27:40 UTC +00:00}, {"feed_text"=>"new submitted to a goal", "time_stamp"=>Thu, 31 Jul 2014 19:27:31 UTC +00:00}, {"feed_text"=>"A new goal has been created:test 6", "time_stamp"=>Thu, 31 Jul 2014 19:27:19 UTC +00:00}, {"feed_text"=>"A new goal has been created:test2", "time_stamp"=>Thu, 31 Jul 2014 14:45:09 UTC +00:00}]

We can't figure out why the page is displaying both the #what_we_want and the #what_we_don't_want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to replace

```
<%= @feed.each do |f| %>
```

with

```
<% @feed.each do |f| %>
```

The `<%=` means to evaluate/execute the code and insert it into the html where as `<%` means to simply evaluate/execute the code